# Fail to sudo apt-get update

Tags: updates

I am not able to sudo apt-get update successfully. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

**Error message:**

```
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
```

More error messages attached in the screenshot.

[image: There are lots of "not signed" and "can't be authenticated" error messages.]

How could I fix it?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Comment: What shows up when you visit [http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) in a browser? Is it the "Index of /ubuntu" page or something else?

Comment: I was not able to post text in here with more than 2 hyperlinks.

Comment: David, the link you posted in here was 50% solution of my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I just rolled back your last edit. Please don't add the answer to your question and please don't duplicate the answers of the linked question. Thanks.

Comment: The link was only 50% for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `--allow-unauthenticated` option to skip it:

```
sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated update
sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated upgrade
```

Or if you have have the id of the missing key (from the output of `apt-get`), you can add it to the apt key manager to be authenticate :

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys put_the missing_key_here
```

Comment: It worked for fixing the missing keys. Thanks.