# sudo apt-get update fails public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY, sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key also fails

Tags: apt, package-management, gnupg

Ubuntu 18.04
For some time now the graphical GUI Software Updater would report

[image]

Then click ok would give me

[image]

Then click Install Now

it would report loading for a fraction of a second then close. I should have been suspicious, but ...

Well, today I tried

> sudo apt-get update

and got the following error

> Get:14 https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any any InRelease
> [23.2 kB]                                              Err:14
> https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any any InRelease   The
> following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
> not available: NO_PUBKEY B7E65990E879472F Reading package lists...
> Done  W: GPG error: https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any any
> InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the
> public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7E65990E879472F E: The
> repository 'https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any any
> InRelease' is not signed.

[askubuntu.com/questions/849919/fail-to-sudo-apt-get-update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849919/fail-to-sudo-apt-get-update)

suggests

> sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated update

but this fails too.

[fix-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available](https://chrisjean.com/fix-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available/)
[many more questions with same answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897660/the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-avai)
[and more](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943539/the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-avai)

suggests

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys xxxx

but this fails too "gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data".

Suggestions for what to do next would be appreciated.

Comment: Disable the bad repo on the Other Software tab of the 
 Software and Updates app.Whatever packages were installed from there will get orphaned, but you should be able to complete the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the repository's webpage (https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/), you'll find a button that leads you to the "*Debian Installation Instructions*" which tell you to download a script and execute it. Said script will pull the required GPG key from https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/gpgkey and feed it into `apt-key`. Alternatively, look at https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/#user-content-debianubuntu-distributions which lists the detailed manual steps.

Comment: does this reload the desktop? I ran what it said "curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/shiftkey/desktop/script.deb.sh | sudo bash" and now "sudo apt-get update" works. The GUI still closes in a fraction of a second, so no idea if this is normal or it is still misbehaving.

Answer (score 4):

[Installation instructions](https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/install)

Run it in the terminal

```
curl -s `https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/shiftkey/desktop/script.deb.sh | sudo bash`
```

[image]

Alternative option. This is the command that will automatically find and add the necessary security keys of the connected repositories:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com `sudo apt-get update 2>&1 | grep -o '[0-9A-Z]\{16\}$' | xargs`
```